# How to pass custom model build in cross_val_predict

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I want to do xgboost survival model with output_margin = True in predict. However, sklearn don't have any method to pass new parameters for predict, but it does have it for fit.

so i have written following class

```
class PredictWithOutputMargin:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.model.predict(self, X, output_margin=True)

    def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        return self.model.fit(X, y, **kwargs)

    def get_params(self, deep = False):
        return self.model.get_params(deep)
```

then I am passing it to

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict as cvp

model = PredictWithOutputMargin(model_instance)
cv_score = cvp(model, train_x, train_y, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, method=method)
```

Here method is predict and cv is 5.

However, when I run code I get following error.

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base_score'`

Any idea how to pass it ?

Comment: Can you add full error dump? I'm interested what actually complains about the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely (in the absence of the full error dump it is just a guess) the problem is in the implementation of `clone` in sklearn. This function is used by the cross validation function [to create copies of the input model and use those to spawn training in parallel threads](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb5b2012412888b69e73d76f2df2b50b6/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L778). The way `clone` works is that it retrieves all parameters from the model and creates an object of the same type with those parameters (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb5b2012412888b69e73d76f2df2b50b6/sklearn/base.py#L62-L65)). So in your case it tries to call `PredictWithOutputMargin(parameters_of_sklearn_model)`, which does to match your constructor.

I guess, the way to overcome this particular issue is to return `{'mode': self.model}` in `PredictWithOutputMargin.get_params()`. But I do not know if this will generate problems somewhere on another stage.